# How to use MAX and Group BY SQL expressions in ArcGIS Pro "Select by Attribute" tool

Tags: sql, arcgis

From a feature class (shapefile) in file geodatabase I want to SELECT rows based on **MAXIMUM** values of a column (i.e., AdjRiverLe) **GROUP BY** another column (i.e, ID). I am not sure how it's done in **ArcGIS Pro** as *SQL sub-queries*. I have multiple ways including this:

```
AdjRiverLe IN (SELECT MAX(AdjRiverLe) FROM Temporary GROUP BY ID)
```

This gives "**Invalid expression**" error.

Does 'GROUP BY' in a nested query work in ArcGIS Pro? If yes, then could you please provide an example with my problem I just mentioned? Thanks.

Comment: Based on your error, I would say the answer is "no".

Answer (score -1):

You write it like this:

```
AdjRiverLe = (SELECT MAX(AdjRiverLe) FROM Temporary GROUP BY ID)
```

Comment: I am looking for a method like this to solve a similar issue I have. Where would you implement this selection in Modelbuilder? I have a feature shp layer with fields "MARK_ID" and "SHAPE_Area". There are multiple SHAPE_Area per individual MARK_ID. I want to select the maximum SHAPE_Area for all MARK_ID. I Tried implementing  "SHAPE_Area = (SELECT MAX(SHAPE_Area)  FROM Marker2022_Jor_PairwiseDisso GROUP BY MARK_ID)" in a Table Select tool without luck.